# I know the command line so what's the netplan yaml?

Tags: networking, 18.04, configuration, 18.10, netplan

in Ubuntu 18.04 (and 18.10) we're finding (on proxmox host) that Ubuntu VM's are losing the lan IP route on restart. We know the command to make them re-add it. But we don't want to have it run it manually. These are [`Class C`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) connections that should not require a gateway.

For refernce this is the command in command line that we have to run every reboot (where 10.90.90.52 is the static client ip) it works perfectly

```
  # ip route add 10.90.90.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.90.90.52
```

I have looked at the [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples#source-routing) but they make no mention of `eth1`.. what is the yaml equivalent of the above working command line?

this is our (not working) `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` we were fiddling with. we know it's not good enough.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens160:
        addresses:
        - 10.90.90.2/24
        dhcp4: false
```

this is the proxmox config

[image]

remember this command `# ip route add 10.90.90.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.90.90.52` ***is*** currently working but when we restart we have to manually run it. We're simply looking for the yaml version of what works by hand.

Answer (score 0):

in the end this worked but we're not entirely happy with what we did

```
# nano /etc/netplan/01-systemd-networkd-eth1.yaml
```

note the two spaces before the word "network: " they matter - yaml is whitespace/ indent sensitive

```
  network:
     version: 2
      ethernets:
        eth1:
          addresses: [10.90.90.52/24]
          dhcp4: false
```

this gives us this on reboot

```
# ip r
default via xx.x2.x18.x7 dev eth0 proto static
10.90.90.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.90.90.52
xx.x2.x18.x7  dev eth0 proto static scope link
```

which is what

```
# ip route add 10.90.90.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.90.90.52
```

was giving us